# Is calling a memoized/primitive class method from within a template different from referencing a class property set in ngOnChanges?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've read that you calling methods from within a template in Angular has negative implications for performance because change detection cannot know if an invoked method will have a different result without invoking it. Moreover, if the return value of the method is not a primitive, it's always going to be treated as different, since the method will always return a new reference.

This is pretty clear to me, but I'm not sure if there's something about invoking a method which matters to change detection in itself.

As in, are these two methods of rendering the `value` different when it comes to change detection?

```
{{ _value }}
{{ computedValue() }}
class MyComponent implements OnChanges {
  _value;
  computeValue() {
    // ... some computation
    return value // primitive type
  }
  ngOnChanges() {
    this._value = computedValue();
  }
}
```